# Using quick sort algorithm to sort objects alongside respective integers

Tags: arrays, sorting, quicksort

I am writing a survey based program in which there is a method for comparing the compatibilities of people with that of the user.

I have a quick sort algorithm that sorts integers from greatest to least efficiently, however I need to sort an array of people alongside the array of integers (which is an array of people's compatibilities). How do I sort the array of people so that they match with their respective integer compatibility?

quick sort algorithm:

```
public static void qsort(People [] ppl, Integer [] a, Integer si, Integer ei){
        //base case
        if(ei<=si || si>=ei){}

        else{ 
            Integer pivot = a[si]; 
            Integer i = si+1; Integer tmp; 

            //partition array 
            for(Integer j = si+1; j<= ei; j++){
                if(pivot < a[j]){
                    tmp = a[j]; 
                    a[j] = a[i]; 
                    a[i] = tmp; 

                    i++; 
                }
            }

            //put pivot in right position
            a[si] = a[i-1]; 
            a[i-1] = pivot; 

            //call qsort on right and left sides of pivot
            qsort(a, si, i-2); 
            qsort(a, i, ei); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void qsort(People [] ppl, Integer [] a, Integer si, Integer ei){
    //base case
    if(ei<=si || si>=ei){}
    else{ 
        Integer pivot = a[si]; 
        People pPivot = ppl[si];
        Integer i = si+1; Integer tmp; People pTmp; 

        //partition array 
        for(Integer j = si+1; j<= ei; j++){
            if(pivot < a[j]){
                tmp = a[j]; 
                pTmp = ppl[j];
                a[j] = a[i]; 
                ppl[j]=ppl[i];
                a[i] = tmp; 
                ppl[i]=pTmp;
                i++; 
            }
        }

        //put pivot in right position
        a[si] = a[i-1]; 
        ppl[si] = ppl[i-1];
        a[i-1] = pivot; 
        ppl[i-1]=pPivot;

        //call qsort on right and left sides of pivot
        qsort(ppl, a, si, i-2); 
        qsort(ppl, a, i, ei); 
    }
}
```